# Interpreting decision boundary - Logistic regression in R

Tags: r, logistic, data-visualization

I have plotted the Decision boundary for my logistic regression but I don't clearly understand how to interpret it. How do I know on which side of the boundary y=1 and on which y=0?

Here is the plot:
[image]

And the code:

```
model <- glm (left ~ satisfaction_level + time_spend_company, family = binomial(link = 'logit'), data = data)
coefs = coef(model)
summary(model)

(x = c(min(data[,1])-2,  max(data[,1])+2))
(y = c((-1/coefs[3]) * (coefs[2] * x + coefs[1])))
lines(x, y, col="black", lwd=2)
```

Can someone explain?

Thanks!

P.S. I have use the [Kaggle HR data set](https://www.kaggle.com/ludobenistant/hr-analytics) with split:

```
data <- HR.2 [1:12000,]
test.data <- HR.2 [12001:14999,]
```

Comment: At a quick glance (just from the visualization), it looks like those below (and to the right) of the decision boundary would be classified as "Remained," and the ones above (and to the left) would be classified as "Left." You can see this by looking farther away from the boundary (close to the boundary, it should be about 50-50).

Comment: Thanks @Kevin, but how can I normally see this from the code or coefficients? And should I plot the boundary together with the training or testing data?

Comment: The logistic function is always increasing, so you can use this rule: If the coefficient of "satisfaction level" is positive, then `y = 1` will be to the right (since `y = 1` would be more likely with a high satisfaction level). Otherwise, it will be to the left.

Since your decision boundary is sloping up, your coefficients (should) be either both positive or both negative, so you'd only need to look at one.

Typically I've always seen boundaries plotted with the testing data; this lets you evaluate (by eye) how well the boundary generalizes.

Comment: thanks @Kevin, but in fact the coefficients are with opposite signs: "Satisfaction level" ( -3.654 ) has negative impact on the probability to leave while "time spent with company" ( + 0.224) has a positive impact (people are more likely to leave when they have been with the company for longer time). So to conclude - the observation in the upper left corner are more likely to leave while the employees in the lower right will remain?

Comment: My bad, I had the two reversed (they should actually be opposite; with a downward sloping decision boundary, they would be the same). The rest of what I said was correct.

And yes, that conclusion is correct given the signs of the coefficients :)